# Transposing a specific column into row in python dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I try to transpose a dataframe with a specific format :
Here is my current dataframe called df :
[image]

and the result of transpose shoud be :
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have following dataframe , using `unstack`

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'pid':[1,1,1],'TreeFeature':['a','b','c'],'Import':[1,2,3],'acc':[1,1,1]})
df.set_index(['pid','acc','TreeFeature']).Import.unstack().reset_index()
Out[298]: 
TreeFeature  pid  acc  a  b  c
0              1    1  1  2  3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [`pd.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
res = df.pivot_table(index=['pid', 'Accuracy'], columns=['TreeFeatures'],
                     values='Importance 1', aggfunc='first', fill_value=0)
```

If you need to elevate index to columns, reset index via `res.reset_index()`.